# How to delete 100 thousand emails all at once?

Tags: gmail

I have this about 100 thousand emails in my Gmail, good thing it is under the "All Mail" label.

How can I delete all my emails at once?

The Gmail interface can only display 100 emails per page, what's the workaround to delete all emails at once?

Comment: select all visible, after that you will get the link "Select all conversations that match this search" and then delete

Comment: @Zina Please remember that answers belong in the answer section. Please also avoid repeating what others have said. Please take a look at marikamitsos' answer and you will see they are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### To delete all messages within a label

**Please follow these steps**

**1.** Choose the label in question.
**2.** Select All
**3.** Once you select `All` a new choice will appear. Click on it.

[image: How to delete all messages within a label in Gmail]

Comment: sadly this option is now limited to just the current page.  I swear Gmail did this so people can't clean up their inboxes, so now instead they have to upgrade... shadiest shit ever considering they used to advertise "never delete an email again" and now they remove the very feature to avoid a full inbox...

Answer (score -1):

I would connect with IMAP with some other client (thunberbird or claws-mail),
and then delete it.

Or You can open developer console in web-browser and try to write