# all messages moved to trash in gmail does not work bulk deleting emails

Tags: email, gmail

I have subscribed to many mailing lists. I have thousands of emails and filters in my email.
I try to delete 10,000 emails at a time but I can not delete them.I get messages that conversations have been moved to trash where as they are not moved to trash.
Here are a few screenshots that will help understand situation.
[image: gmail selecting all ten thousand messages]
[image: messages loading]
[image]
[image]

so only 50 emails got delted where as I selected all 10,000 emails . So what should I do to change this situation?

Comment: Welcome. Have you gone through all the steps as mentioned [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/142779)? If you did and still failed to delete all messages please let us know. If the steps worked just upvote the answer :)

Comment: yes that is what I have written in question I went through all the steps as given in your link and still bulk deleting of emails did not worked.

Comment: hmmm. It could be that your computer RAM is not enough. Could you try it from another, more powerful machine? Or as a test, try selecting say just 1.000 or 500 and see if it responds as it should.

Comment: I am having 12Gb ram on this laptop

Comment: Well... :/ Someone else may chip in.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is working through the list of messages/conversations. I am basing this on the numbers I see in your screen captures.

```
image 1: 10300 conversations; 10027 unread; most recent message 10:03 PM June 1st.
image 2: 10300 conversations; 10027 unread; most recent message 10:03 PM June 1st.
image 3: 10300 conversations; 10027 unread; most recent message 10:03 PM June 1st.
image 4: 10300 conversations; 6672 unread; most recent message from December 2013.
```

Gmail has already moved about 3300 messages from the specified label. If left to continue the rest of them should continue to move to trash.

Answer (score 0):

As you have thousands of messages to be deleted it will take a while to completely remove all of them from the Web UI.

Take note of the total number of messages to be deleted then check again in 24 hours. If the number of messages was not reduced send your feedback directly to Google by clicking on the gear button > Send Feedback and post a question on the Gmail official help forum.